# Don't show closed questions on "Questions with extreme votes"

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, 10k-tools

On the `/tools` page, the first item at the top are the lowest voted questions.

I thought this feature was to help identify poor quality questions, but if they are already closed who cares?

Comment: Closed questions with extreme downvotes might benefit from a deletion vote (or two, or three).

Comment: But what about the other low voted questions that aren't visible because the really bad closed ones are on top?

Comment: There are several views available in the 10K tools.  Recently closed, recently opened.  You can have them for the last 7 days, the last 30 days, etc.

Comment: @Robert, Sure. But for today, I cannot view questions with votes less than 6. As SO traffic gets higher this number will continue to go up. Maybe what I want is a way to see all questions in time period y with at least x downvotes. Is there a way to do that?